# Why doesn't !Imporant override previous settings here

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph:

```
<body>
<div id="attachment_839" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 462px">
<p class="wp-caption-text">Pargraph text which is much wider than 270px</p>
</div>
<body>
```

and styling applied:

```
body{
    width:270px !important; 
}
```

The question is:

Why this paragraph is much too wide? As the `!important` was used to override previous settings and style page my way.

To solve the problem I have added following code:

```
.wp-caption-text {
     width: 270px ! important;
}
```

It's proven and it works, but why does `!important` not override previous width? What can I do to find possible answers?

Comment: It's not that the `!important` isn't working, you just aren't targeting the right element. To achieve what you want you would have to target `.wp-caption` like this: `.wp-caption { width: 270px !important; }`

Answer (score 4):

A paragraph `<p>` without a declared width takes up the whole width of the parent container ( because of the default `auto` ).

In your case with the width defined - it breaks out of the parent.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sxrkq)

If you delete `style="width: 462px"` from your `div` - it won't break the layout anymore

Comment: I can't see anything being overridden here though. There is an inline style on the `div` and there are CSS rules for `body` and `.wp-caption-text`.

Comment: @BoltClock it's not overriding - the paragraph just wider because the inline style is more important than the general width style http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sxrkq

Comment: In your comment, you're implying that the inline style overrides the general width style. That's wrong. There's no overriding going on - the paragraph is stretching out because it's wider than the div, but that's it. I suspect the `!important` bits are nothing more than red herrings here.

Comment: @BoltClock Maybe my wording isn't absolutely precise but that's just to illustrate what's going on. The `<p>` without a declared width takes up the whole width of the parent container ( because of the default `auto` ). And with the width defined - it breaks out of the parent.

Comment: @ZoltanToth exactly - and this has nothing to do with `!important`, overriding or inline-styles. And btw the body `!important` rule override the inline rule it it was on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered, I am just adding my observations.

I tried the code given in question and found that the paragraph width is 270px where as div width is 420px. So no override is done using !important.

`!imporatant` can override only external styles, it cannot override any inline-styles.
In this case we have declared div's width as inline-style. So if we will add width in `.wp-caption` class declaration and use `!important`, this will not affect the div's width.

In order to verify the width I have added border to the paragraph and div. Below is the styles defined.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    width:270px !important; 
}
.wp-caption-text {
     width: 270px !important;
     border: 1px dotted green;
}
.wp-caption
{
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
</style>
```

The screenshot shows the paragraph width and div width.
[image]